# Assign Procedure to Variable in Excel VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, class, procedure, assign

## 1.Intro

I need to assign procedures to variables in Excel VBA as I did it in other languages before. Later on these variables shall be used to call the corresponding procedure. I’d like to avoid case instructions for 4 x 30 procedures.
Unfortunately I tried everything I could think of and searched the web but nothing worked. So I hope someone can have an eye on it and will probably immediately see which magic word is missing.
In case this kind of programming is not available with VBA I would be thankful if someone can confirm this to me.
I simplified my code for better focusing on the problem and composed the essential part below. This should allow to reproduce the error.

Thanks in advance, Mounty

## 2. Infrastructure

PC: Win7Enterprise-64 SP1, Excel 365 ProPlus-32 (1808)

## 3. Code

### Class Module

```
'in StepClass_Module
Public proc As Variant          'proc = procedure to run
```

### Programming Module

```
Public step(1) As StepClass_Module      'Declare array of procedures  

Sub main()  
   Set step(0) = New StepClass_Module  
   Set step(1) = New StepClass_Module  

   Set step(0).proc = Import()         'Should allocate corresponding Procedure but runs it => error 13  
   Set step(1).proc = Prepare()        'Should allocate corresponding Procedure but runs it => error 13  

   Run step(0).proc                    'Run corresponding Procedure  
   Run step(1).proc                    'Run corresponding Procedure  
End Sub


Function Import() As Variant  
   Debug.Print ("Import")  
End Function

Function Prepare() As Variant  
   Debug.Print ("Prepare")  
End Function
```

Comment: Just pass the name of the procedure as a string. That's what `Run` expects.

Comment: Hi Rony, I thank you so much for saving me so much time. I was hoping it is a small topic but never considered "Run". I adapted my code just for someone stepping into the same problem. I looks like I can not do this in a comment. I'll try an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following model:

```
Sub main()
    Dim s As String
    s = "inputt,makereport,outputt"
    arr = Split(s, ",")

    For Each a In arr
        Run a
    Next a
End Sub

Sub inputt()
    MsgBox "input"
End Sub

Sub makereport()
    MsgBox "reporting"
End Sub

Sub outputt()
    MsgBox "dun"
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Gary, now understanding your code, the major message for me is, that Run has to be used with the procedure name as a string what I did not (know). This change solved my problem. Thank you very much for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

Here comes the updated code as I wanted to have it functioning and now it works! Big help!

Class Module
    ============

```
    'in StepClass_Module  
    Public proc As String          'proc = procedure to run  

Programming Module
==================

Public step(1) As StepClass_Module      'Declare array of procedures  

Sub main()  
   Set step(0) = New StepClass_Module  
   Set step(1) = New StepClass_Module  

   step(0).proc = "Import"         'allocate corresponding Procedure  
   step(1).proc = "Prepare"        'allocate corresponding Procedure  

   Run step(0).proc                'Run corresponding Procedure  
   Run step(1).proc                'Run corresponding Procedure  
End Sub  



Sub Import()  
   Debug.Print ("Import")  
End Sub  

Sub Prepare()  
   Debug.Print ("Prepare")  
End Sub
```